# Show Hide Elements based on function

Tags: angular

I have an observable that i get from my authentication service that tells me if a user is logged in. I want certain elements to be visible in my header depending on what page my user is visiting. I have created two functions that return boolean.

If a user is NOT logged in then an element should be visible. If a user is in the log in page then an element should NOT be visbile.

```
isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn;



  }

  shouldShowBlueBanner(): boolean {

    if (this.pageName === '/login') {
      return false;
    }
  }

  shouldShowRegisterLink(): boolean {
    if (!this.isLoggedIn$) {

      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }


}

  <div id="registerLink" *ngIf="shouldShowRegisterLink">
    <a [routerLink]="['/register']" >

      Register</a>
  </div>
  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
    <div id="blueheader"  *ngIf="shouldShowBlueBanner">
    </div>
</div>
```

How do i show/hide Divs based on return value from my functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *ngIf directive with a functions.

```
  *ngIf="isActive()"
```

Comment: This is working for the one function. In my other function i have if(this.isLoggedIn$){return false;}Else{return true;} and it isnt working. Is it because isLoggedIn$ is an observable?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with only one variable which you called `isLoggedIn`. After user logs in, the value will change to `true`, and `*ngIf` will hide first element with negation `!`, and show the other element without negation.

```
isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn;



  }
}

  <div id="registerLink" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
    <a [routerLink]="['/register']" >

      Register</a>
  </div>
  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
    <div id="blueheader"  *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use async pipe like isLoggedIn | async ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngIf else

example:

```
 <div *ngIf="isLoggedIn"; else noData">
         Show Data
      </div>
<ng-template><div>No Data </div></ng-template>
```